# How to decode a nested JSON object in an array in an object?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I need to retrieve data deep within a nested JSON but I've had alot of trouble doing so. The file in question can be found at https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&indent=on&sites=08155200&parameterCd=00065&siteStatus=all.

```
// MARK: - Post
struct Post: Codable {
    let name, declaredType, scope: String?
    let value: PostValue?
    let postNil, globalScope, typeSubstituted: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, declaredType, scope, value
        case postNil
        case globalScope, typeSubstituted
    }
}

// MARK: - PostValue
struct PostValue: Codable {
    let queryInfo: QueryInfo?
    let timeSeries: [TimeSery]?
}

// MARK: - QueryInfo
struct QueryInfo: Codable {
    let queryURL: String?
    let criteria: Criteria?
    let note: [Note]?
}

// MARK: - Criteria
struct Criteria: Codable {
    let locationParam, variableParam: String?
    let parameter: [JSONAny]?
}

// MARK: - Note
struct Note: Codable {
    let value, title: String?
}

// MARK: - TimeSery
struct TimeSery: Codable {
    let sourceInfo: SourceInfo?
//    let variable: Variable?
//    let values: [TimeSeryValue]?
    let name: String?
}

// MARK: - SourceInfo
struct SourceInfo: Codable {
    let siteName: String?
//    let siteCode: [SiteCode]?
//    let timeZoneInfo: TimeZoneInfo?
    let geoLocation: GeoLocation?
    let note, siteType: [JSONAny]?
//    let siteProperty: [SiteProperty]?
}

// MARK: - GeoLocation
struct GeoLocation: Codable {
    let geogLocation: GeogLocation?
    let localSiteXY: [JSONAny]?
}

// MARK: - GeogLocation
struct GeogLocation: Codable {
    let srs: String?
    let latitude, longitude: Double?
}
```

The code to retrieve the data:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
    if let data = data {
        let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: data)
        if let coord = (posts.value?.timeSeries?.sourceInfo?.geoLocation?.geogLocation?.srs) {
            print(coord)
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

Unfortunately, this returns with the error

```
error: ParseJSON.playground:330:89: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeSeries` is defined as `[TimeSery]`, meaning it's an array, but you're trying to access it as if it's just a single value. Since I'm not sure what your intent was, it's hard to say what the exact fix is, but one possibility is accessing the `first` value from it (the equivalent of asking for `[0]`, but it returns an Optional):

```
posts.value?.timeSeries?.first?.sourceInfo?.geoLocation?.geogLocation?.srs
```

---

A way to debug this issue, by the way, is to break down the expression into less-complex parts (I started with just `posts.value` and add code back until you find the issue (in this case, `timeSeries.sourceInfo`)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've debugged it and it works with `posts.value?.timeSeries` but if I enter `posts.value?.timeSeries?.sourceInfo?` it gives the error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`.

Comment: Yes -- check out my answer -- `timeSeries` is an array. You can't access `sourceInfo` on it directly because you need to tell it which element you want. This is why I suggested *maybe* using `.first`. But, I don't know *which* element you want.